# How can I monitor/check outgoing DNS lookup connections?

Tags: internet-connection, dns

When using the various CLI network monitors like LSOF, Netstat, ifTop. I'd like to see what applications are doing DNS lookups (using port 53 over UDP). How do I configure so that these connections are shown in the Terminal? I'd like to see what IP Address is being connected to and what applications are requesting the DNS lookup.

I'm interested in any way to learn this information.

Answer (score 3):

You must turn on bind / named logging:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bind9utils
$ rndc querylog
```

Then, you can see the log the service in the system log:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Once finished, you can turn off logging again:

```
$ rndc querylog
```

Comment: I believe that this would require BIND to be running. The question sounds more geared towards desktops

Comment: Then, may be he had to capture traffic using ethereal / wireshark. He should filter the packages having destination port = 53

Answer (score 2):

For those interested I just discovered the `dnstop` CLI tool ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dnstop)), which­­–given a network interface–can show you a live updated view of DNS queries made by your machine. It can group and sort by any level of subdomain depth, client IP, record type, etc...

Here is a [nice tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dnstop-monitor-bind-dns-server-dns-network-traffic-from-a-shell-prompt/#comment-944731).